# Xcode 4 debugger don't show logs in All Outputs for iOS 4.3 SDK

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

I installed the release of Xcode 4 + latest 4.3 iOS version on iPhone. In previous version (GM Seed) I could see logs I printed with NSLog function. In this version I cannot see them. Did somebody run into such a problem and how to solve it?

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem with this one is exactly the same as with its previous versions. In Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport there are missing files in the folder of 4.2.1, 4.3, 4.3.1. Missing files are always the same - just compare these folders with 4.2 for instance and there is a dns.so file, that should be included to Symbols/usr/lib/info folder.
If you don't have all these no chance to debug with device or see logs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that NSLog is not producing output in the debug area (Command+Shift+Y) of Xcode?  If so, ensure that you have "All Output" and "Show the Variables View and the Console" (middle button of three on right) selected, otherwise you may not be seeing the output.

Comment: yes, i'm not seeing the output, that's the problem. only with iOS 4.3